# simple python music quiz

Tags: python, python-3.x, quiz, music

I'm currently learning python and created a simple music quiz. the rules of the game are as follows:

The user has two chances to guess the name of the song If the user guesses the answer correctly the first time, they score 3 points. If the user guesses the answer correctly the second time they score 1 point.The game repeats.The game ends when a player guesses the song name incorrectly the second time.

I developed the following but the I wasn't very pleased with the update leaderboard function as the indexing of the 2d list was confusing to code. is there an easier way to do the same thing?

start_quiz returns two variables and is there a way to sort of 'unpack' what's returned?

```
# 21:23 5th dec 2019
from Resources.songs import songs
from Resources.users import users
import random
import pickle


def main():
    username = login()
    print('hello', username, 'welcome to the music quiz')
    guessed_wrong_twice = False
    result = None
    while not guessed_wrong_twice:
        result = start_quiz()
        guessed_wrong_twice = result[1]
    score = result[0]
    print('you scored', score)
    leaderboard = leaderboard_updating(username, int(result[0]))
    print('The leaderboard:\n', leaderboard)


main()



def login():
    logged_in = False
    entered_username = None
    while not logged_in:
        entered_username = input("please enter username: ")
        if entered_username in users:
            entered_password = input('please enter password: ')
            if entered_password == users[entered_username]:
                logged_in = True
        else:
            print("password or username incorrect try again")
            logged_in = False

    return entered_username



def start_quiz():
    score = 0
    guessed_wrong_twice = False
    song_chosen = choosing_song()
    print('artists name is', song_chosen[1])
    first_letter = song_chosen[0][0]
    guess = input("the song begins with" + first_letter)
    if guess.lower == song_chosen[0]:
        score += 3
    else:
        guess = input("the song begins with " + first_letter)
        if guess.lower == song_chosen[0]:
            score += 1
        elif guess != song_chosen[0]:
            guessed_wrong_twice = True
    return score, guessed_wrong_twice


def choosing_song():
    song_chooser = random.randint(1, 3)
    song_artist = songs[song_chooser][1]
    song_name = songs[song_chooser][0]
    return song_name, song_artist

# index 0 of each 'sub list' is the users name index 1 is their highest score

def leaderboard_updating(username, score=0):

    leaderboard = pickle.load(open("leaderboard.pickle", "rb"))

    index_row_list = [leaderboard.index(row) for row in leaderboard if username in row]
    index_row = int(index_row_list[0])
    if leaderboard[index_row][1] < score:
        leaderboard[index_row][1] = score

    leaderboard = sorted(leaderboard, key=lambda x: x[1])

    pickle.dump(leaderboard, open("leaderboard.pickle", "wb"))
    return leaderboard
```

Comment: The code in the question doesn't work, as detailed in my CW disposable answer below.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>**Note**: Not an answer, an [extended comment](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6977).</sup>

There's no way your code can work the way you intend it to.

1. Your leader board doesn't work when the user isn't already in the leader board.

   The second line will `IndexError` in these cases:

   > ```
   > index_row_list = [leaderboard.index(row) for row in leaderboard if username in row]
   > index_row = int(index_row_list[0])
   > ```
2. You can never score more than 3 points on the leader board.

   > ```
   > while not guessed_wrong_twice:
   >     result = start_quiz()
   >     guessed_wrong_twice = result[1]
   > score = result[0]
   > ```
3. You can never enter a correct song.

   > ```
   > if guess.lower == song_chosen[0]:
   > ```

   Looks innocent enough, but it's never true. Unless `song_chosen[0]` is `str.lower`. In which case it's always true.

   ```
   >>> 'abc'.lower == 'abc'
   False
   ```

Now 1 & 2 are pretty minor, so if your code only contained them I'd just answer. But 3 means it's impossible for your code to work.

Given that `start_quiz` was the last function I reviewed I have a half written review for you. Please fix the above problems for it.

Comment: with number 3 would `guess == songchosen[0]: ` be correct?

Comment: @Krishna Yes and no. It would work, but obviously `"Foo"  != "foo"`.

Comment: so I would have to convert `song chosen[0]` to lowercase as well as `guess` before the if statement?

Comment: @Krishna Before / in doesn't really matter. But yes if you wish to be pedantic about 'correctness' you would have to do that. Which is why I say the answer is yes and no.